# GPVAL_Y_MIN not found in gnuplot 4.6

Tags: gnuplot

`show variables all` command lists my available variables where `GPVAL_Y_MIN` or `GPVAL_Y_MAX` are not found (`GPVAL_VERSION` = 4.6 and terminal is set to aqua). I am trying to subtract minimum value from Y-Axis on the fly by the following way but with no success,

```
ymin = GPVAL_Y_MIN
plot "file.dat" every 10 u 4:($7-ymin) w p
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

`GPVAL_Y_MIN` is only set once you actually plot some data.  One old solution is to set the terminal to dummy, make the "plot" and then reset the terminal to something useful before plotting again.

However, starting at gnuplot 4.6, you have the `stats` command available to you.

```
stats 'file.dat' e 10 u 4:7
plot 'file.dat' e 10 u 4:($7-STATS_min_y)
```

I think will do what you're asking (untested)

Comment: Thanks but <stats 'file.dat' e 10 u 4:$7> gives the error "Expecting [no]output or prefix".

Comment: For some reason they did not work before. But now it is working! Thanks again!

Comment: There is a wrong `$` character in the `stats` command, it should be `stats 'file.dat' e 10 u 4:7`.

Comment: @Christoph -- Thanks.  I've not really used the `stats` command a whole lot.  I'm a little surprised it doesn't accept the standard `$` using syntax.

Comment: It uses the same `using` syntax as `plot`, but `using 4:$7` is wrong in any case, `using 4:($7)` works.

Comment: @Christoph -- facepalm :-/.  Cheers.  You can tell I've not used gnuplot for the past 6 months.  My skills are getting a bit rusty.